# How does the Controller know the Id on DeleteConfirmed in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi can someone please explain how the default delete method generated by Visual Studio work. I am confused because when you Post `DeleteConfirmed` the model `Id` is passed back to controller. But in the View there is no `Id` field generated not even in a hidden field so how come `Id` is not lost/reset on Post? How does the Controller know the `Id`?

**View**

```
   @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
    }

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>SellersQuery</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            SellersQuery sellersquery = db.SellerQuerySet.Find(id);
            if (sellersquery == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(sellersquery);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            SellersQuery sellersquery = db.SellerQuerySet.Find(id);
            db.SellerQuerySet.Remove(sellersquery);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: What's the URL of this webpage?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thanks I just checked it. But if you are doing AJAX or other dynamic stuff do u need to put a Hidden Id field?

Comment: Yeah. I guess, the id is obtained rather from: '/mycontroller-like-home/myaction-like-confirm/myid-like-5/.

Comment: But the form is generated by default for not AJAX. So, if you want to do that manually -- just do it manually and add that hidden field (or any other way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GET Delete` URL is probably something like this `/Controller/Action/Id`.
So even if you don't have an `ID` field in your form, the `ID` in the URL is mapped to the `ID` in the method parameter when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the form tag ,if you check it you will find that the action is ControllerName/Delete/Id and this is from where the Id comes , the default routing do the job .